# Make a replica of NSString

Tags: objective-c

I want to modify a NSString with reference to other string in Objective C, Can somebody help me.

**Example1:**

```
a. "ab cd eg"
b. "ctghml"

I want to change string b like "ct gh ml" , in short want to insert space spaces exactly like string a.

Note: Number of letters will be same like (abcdeg).count = 6 and (ctghml).count = 6
```

**Example2:**

```
a. (abcd) edt-tf
b. (lght)ert-tg

I want to change string b like "(lght) ert-tg" , in short want to insert space spaces exactly like string a.

Note: Number of letters will be same without spaces like ((abcd)edt-tf).count = 12 and ((lght)ert-tg).count = 12
```

Thanks!

Comment: only the space character will be diff between them?

Comment: yes, only spaces are the difference.

Comment: how you identify that ,where you want to add white space.Or logic behind to decide add space in string so that we can make a regular expression for it.

Comment: one way is traverse the spaced string and insert the space accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *str1 = @"ab cd eg";
NSMutableString *str2 = [@"ctghml" mutableCopy];

for(int i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
  unichar c = [str1 characterAtIndex:i];
  if (c == ' ') {
    [str2 insertString:@" " atIndex:i];
  }
}

NSLog(@"%@", str2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, let me check.